# Why does TensorFlow's sampled softmax loss stop gradients on sampled classes?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, softmax, loss

The backbone of TensorFlow's sampled loss functions `nce_loss` and `sampled_softmax_loss` is a [helper function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8fb12848d3a81a010714a4612ffd735106ea83d8/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L961) in `tensorflow.python.ops.nn_impl` called `_compute_sampled_logits`.

`_compute_sampled_logits` takes as input:

- weights and biases of the final layer,
- the output labels
- the inputs to the final layer inputs
- the sampled values of the output layer

and return the logits and labels of only the requested sampled labels.

One of the first ([line 1046](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8fb12848d3a81a010714a4612ffd735106ea83d8/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1046-L1047)) ops executed in `_compute_sampled_logits` is

```python
sampled, true_expected_count, sampled_expected_count = (
        array_ops.stop_gradient(s) for s in sampled_values)
```

This line seems like it is stopping gradients flowing back through the sampled values if i'm reading it correctly.

**My questions is**: Shouldn't the gradients be stopped from flowing back through the *non-sampled values* as opposed to the *sampled values*? Why do we want to stop gradients flowing back from the sampled values?
`